# Do Community Wiki Serves as Blogs Also

Tags: support, community-wiki, blog, not-a-real-question

Say a particular question has no specific answers, in fact they are more about asking for crowds opinions and experience.

For example, a question might be, "Your Failed project experience".

These kind of questions usually come in Blogs and its not actually a question. Can community Wiki serve this purpose?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You already answered your own question, such topics belong [on a blog!](http://blog.superuser.com)

Comment: I see, if these are to go to a Blog, then is there any such blog where SO users are shared. The blog link at the bottom is for Admins to publish info about SO and not a community blog.

Comment: You could make a case for a community maintained SO blog either here on Meta or discuss it in the [Stack Exchange Community blog room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/115/stack-exchange-community-blogs)

Answer (score 3):

No it can't.

Questions where

> every answer is equally valid: “What’s your favorite ______?”

are explicitly mentioned in the FAQ in the "**What kind of questions should I *not* ask here?**" section.

[From the FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/faq)

Answer (score 1):

> "Your Failed project experience"

This is actually a topic for Programmers.SE, and on programmers the topics can be an inch more open-ended. However just that headline is still way too vague. Survey-like questions are often accepted if you phrase it non-boringly. Add some specifica, and at the very least ask for practical advise.

If it is however not a question at all, and it is clear that you are not interested in answers or solutions but just a discussion of past events, then it does not belong.

Making it Community Wiki is not a workaround then.

Comment: The same clause I mention is also in the Programmers [FAQ](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/faq) so the topic as described isn't Programmers material either.

Comment: @ChrisF: It's foremost not PSE material because it has been covered more thouroughly and with specifics before. And my recommendation wants to be read under the premise that the question does not amount to *"What's your favourite _____ failed project experience?"*

Comment: Fair point, but it's better to make that point explicitly.

Comment: OPs misunderstanding is not just the non-question part. But I can't find the discussion right now which explains the Community Wiki guidelines. (There was a nice one..)